# how do you do hasClass on a dynamic item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

on click event for a dynamically created item is something like this.

`$('.static_parent').on('click','a', function () {`

bur now Im trying to see if a element has a class, but its on a dynamic items.
I tried a few variations of this but cant get it to work.

`$('.input-group',this).hasClass('open')` but surely the `on` will need to play a role in some way... or not?

I have multiple occurrences of `.input-group` and each has a dropdown where is class of `open` is added on click.

But what I dont get is how to test `hasClass` on the dynamic added dropdown.

**Maybe a variation of this**

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.button', function(e){
    var $button = $(this);
    var $menu = $button.closest('.menu');
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Close others-assumed you want all menus closed
    $('.menu').not($menu).removeClass('open'); 

    // Toggle target open/close
    $menu.toggleClass('open');

    $(document).on('click', function(e){
        //This function will only run when e.target isn't a button
        //Your $target.is($menu.find('button')) will always be false

        if( $menu.hasClass('open') ){
            $menu.removeClass('open');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your delegated event handler (as in the first snippet) is the correct code to use, you just need to ensure that the primary selector (`.static_parent` in your case) exists when the DOM initially loads.

Comment: Yes, `.static_parent` is there on load, but I don fully understand your comment. Do you mean. Ho is this implemented for `hasClass`?